# All X is Y but not all Y is X

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a specific word to describe a concept such that its meaning is linear and one-way. Such is the case for the title of this question. X would be of this concept and Y would not, Y would be the opposite of this concept.

For example, all automobiles are motor vehicles but not all motor vehicles are automobiles.

I cannot seem to find any word to relate to this.

Any advice/guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: A banana is a **type** of fruit.

Comment: Your question is vague. What do you mean by "linear and one-way"? Why is X, and not Y, of this concept? What concept?

Comment: "Opposite" is not a well-defined term for most properties. What is the opposite of the Eiffel Tower? Only linear categories can have opposites. See Ken Hale's _Notes on a Walbiri tradition of antonymy_

Comment: _All squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares._ I realize that's not a single word, but that readily-understood analogy is one I've used several times in situations you're describing. [Others like that one, too](https://www.google.com/#q=%22all+squares+are+rectangles,+but+not+all%22&tbm=bks). By the way, some programmers might call this _inheritance_.

Answer (score 9):

X is a *type*, a *category*, or most generally, a ***subset*** of Y.

Conversely, Y is a *supercategory* or *superset* of X.

Answer (score 1):

In linguistics, the concept is called [*hyponymy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy). "Automobile" is a *hyponym* of "motor vehicle"; conversely, "motor vehicle" is a *hypernym* of "automobile".

An easy way to remember which one's which is to keep in mind that just like with other words starting with *hyper-* and *hypo-*, the former stands for "more, greater", and the latter means "less, smaller". *Hypernym* is for the bigger superset, while *hyponym* is for the smaller subcategory.

And of course a hypernym, in turn, can be a hyponym of something else, a bigger superset still. So in your example, "motor vehicle" could be a hyponym of "vehicle", which in turn could be a hyponym of "noun", which in turn could be a hyponym of "word".

So with this, you have a complete set of accurate terms, one for each side in the relationship as well as one for the relationship itself. The terminology is well-established, though the general public is more familiar with some of the other -nyms and -nymies, for other relationships, like *synonyms* or *metonymy*. Still, this site for example does have a rather well-populated [dedicated tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypernyms?sort=votes&pageSize=50) for questions about hypernyms.

Answer (score 0):

Implies works I think. A implies B means that if A is true then B is true but it doesn't necessarily mean B implies A. If both were true you would say A is true if and only if B is true.

So for your example: A is a automobile implies that A is a motor vehicle.

Comment: You might want to make that X and Y? Good answer, though. :)